# Help with multiple inputs and responding to how long the inputs have been active

Tags: rpi.gpio, python-2.x, sendemail

I'm using python 2.7.13 on a Raspberry Pi 3

The goal of my program is to send an email when an input is received (input goes low and I'm using software pull-ups) and then send out another email with a different message when the input goes off (high). There are 12 inputs - each one will be connected to a dry contact, and the coil voltage is connected to an ammonia alarm. The emails will say "Ammonia Alarm #1 is active, troubleshoot immediately" when the input is received, and "Ammonia Alarm #1 is cleared, troubleshooting not needed" when the input clears.

All of that is working in my code and the circuits connected to the Pi. What I'm asking for help on is sending out an email every 30 minutes that the input is active while still being able to respond to any of the other 11 inputs.

What I've tried so far is

```
def Room_1_A_Ammonia_Alarm(channel):
#time.now = current time
global body
if GPIO.input(17) == 1:      
    body = 'A - Building, Room - 1 Ammonia alarm has been cleared'
    Emails()

else:
    now = datetime.now()
    plus20secs = now + timedelta(seconds=20)
    body = 'A - Building, Room - 1 Ammonia alarm has been triggered'
    Emails()
    while GPIO.input(17) == 0:
        if plus20secs > now:
            Emails()
            print ('waiting for 20 secs')
            now = datetime.now()
    print 'done waiting'
```

This callback is connected to:

```
# Detect when input changes state, from rising to falling, or falling to 
rising
GPIO.add_event_detect(17, GPIO.BOTH, callback=Room_1_A_Ammonia_Alarm, 
bouncetime=300)
```

- I changed the code to wait for 20 seconds only for troubleshooting purposes.
  The way it is written, when the program is in the While loop and I turn on the other inputs, they will only respond to the "Ammonia alarm is cleared" section of the function but will not send the email saying "Ammonia alarm has been triggered".
- The second issue is trying to restart the loop so if it goes another 20 seconds, send another email. Right now, it will  send one more email after the initial 20 seconds.

Comment: Python problem, not Pi.

Comment: Is the rpi.GPIO library not specific to the pi? How can I post an issue about python that includes pi specific libraries/functions on a website that doesn't deal the pi?

Comment: If you demonstrate the problem is  an error in RPi.GPIO then it probably would be relevant to this site.   Is there an error in RPi.GPIO?

Comment: The RPi.GPIO is not responding correctly when one of the callback functions is in a while loop. Was hoping for some clarification on why that is and some suggestions on a better plan of attack. At this point, I plan to have the main thread check the inputs every thirty minutes, and if there is a low input (meaning an alarm is triggered) then send an email. I would prefer to go the route I was looking into before where each callback function could check every x minutes and send an email out, but only if the other inputs would respond and trigger the other callbacks.

Comment: Treat a callback as the system treats interrupts.  Do the minimal amount of work in the callback and return.  Never use delays or perform long time actions within a callback as this blocks further calls.  Set a flag and test/clear that flag in a branch of your main code.

Comment: I don't get to understand the problem you have. First you say that the e-mail "Ammonia alarm has been triggered" is not sent. Then you say it is being sent twice. Then you mention another e-mail which has to be sent every 30 minutes, which is not mentioned in the code at all.